# How to add Header in Retrofit2

Tags: java, jwt, retrofit2

I am confused, I have saved the Token in SharedPrefernce, and when I tried to get a Username I could not still null the object preference even though I already used the Header and Sharedpref token. maybe my mistake is not giving Header to the retrofit. here I am confused fatherly adding the header. I have used existing references, but it did not work. I beg if there is a way out I really hope you help me.

RetrofitClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {

        SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
        private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

        public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                                        .build();

            if (retrofit == null){
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(client)
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }
    }
```

this token save

```
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
sharedPrefManager.getSPToken()
```

Comment: Where are you using sharedPrefManager reference at?

Comment: `SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager; `
`sharedPrefManager.getSPToken()`  
this @toffo

Comment: this https://prnt.sc/qd51e3 @toffo

Comment: Ok, but you are not using getSPtoken() result in your code ? But you are looking for interceptor i guess take a look at this https://gist.github.com/alex-shpak/da1e65f52dc916716930 .

Comment: That's right, I'm lacking an intermediary to save my token and put it in retrofit.

from the link you sent in this case I didn't use the refresh token, is there any code for this? @toffor

Comment: not work https://prnt.sc/qd5g8l @toffor

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qd5h6y this code , im get email result @toffor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample retrofit client

```
 public class RetrofitClient {


        private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

        public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
            HeaderInterceptor interceptor = new HeaderInterceptor();
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build();

            if (retrofit == null){
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(client)
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }
    }
```

Interceptor for your use case.

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager();

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request originalRequest = chain.request();

        Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Language", sharedPrefManager.getSPToken())
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);

    }
}
```